# Python: How to add datetime to x-axis in pcolormesh

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

With matplotlib scatter or line plots I can assign the x-axis as an array of datetimes.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 10

# List of Dates
base = datetime.today()
date_list = [base - timedelta(weeks=x) for x in range(0, size)]

plt.figure(1)
a = np.random.random([size])
plt.plot(date_list,a)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

[image]

I would like to make a pcolormesh plot with datetime as the x-axis, but get an error

This works, but not what I want...

```
b = np.random.random([size,size])
plt.figure(2)
c = np.arange(0,size)
plt.pcolormesh(c,c,b)
```

[image]

This throws and error...

```
plt.figure(3)
plt.pcolormesh(date_list,c,b)
```

If you can't feed pcolormesh with a datetime array, is there another way to format the x-axis as dates?

### Update

The issue seems to have been resolved in an updated version of matplotlib. Adding datetimes to a pcolormesh xaxis now works (version 3.4.3)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 10

b = np.random.random([size, size])

# List of Dates
base = datetime.today()
date_list = [base - timedelta(hours=x) for x in range(0, size)]

c = np.arange(0,size)

plt.pcolormesh(date_list, c, b, shading='auto')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 20

base = datetime.today()

x_axis = [base - timedelta(weeks=x) for x in range(0, size)]
y_axis = np.arange(0,size)
data = np.random.random([size,size])

plt.pcolormesh(x_axis, y_axis, data, shading='auto')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=0.2, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=None)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 10

# List of Dates
base = datetime.now()
date_list = [base - timedelta(weeks=x) for x in range(0, size)]
date_list = [i.strftime("%Y %m %d") for i in date_list]

b = np.random.random([size,size])
plt.figure(2)
c = np.arange(0,size)
plt.pcolormesh(c,c,b)
plt.xticks(c, date_list, rotation='vertical')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your dates look a bit funny.. `%M` is _"Minute as a zero-padded decimal number"_, for month you need `%m` (_Month as a zero-padded decimal number_)

Comment: @Bart. Oh, yeah. I hope now it's ok.

Comment: Thanks! After looking around for more help is sounds like pcolormesh just has datetime issues. This is the easiest way to add the dates--labeling with xticks.

Answer (score 3):

I just found out that you can use datetime like dtype in `np.meshgrid`.

This means you don't have to manually format the time axis. Also, when you zoom into the plot, the time axis automatically scales as well.

```
plt.pcolormesh(
    *np.meshgrid(time_array, y_axis_array),
    data_2D_array
)
```

here `time_array.dtype` is a datetime like object. Thus far I have tried using `pd.Timestamp`, my guess is that it should work for the others as well